# How model.addAttribute() works behind the scenes?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Java and Spring Boot. I searched for model.addAttribute() how it really works behind the scenes, but I didn't get any satisfactory answer. Can you explain how it works?

Comment: It adds an attribute to the model, which basically is just a map, which in the end is exposed as request attributes. So not sure what you want to know more but that kind of all there is to it.

Comment: What I really want to understand is that how the value is available to JSP pages when we set it from model.addAttribute()?

Comment: Because it is a map that is exposed as request attributes, request attributes are available to a jsp.

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ModelAttribute
public void addAttributes(Model theModel) {
    theModel.addAttribute("welcome", "Welcome to the stack-overflow!");
}
```

In the above example you can see a method that adds an attribute named "welcome" to all models defined in the controller class.
In general, Spring-MVC will always make a call first to that method, before it calls any request handler methods.
It is important to focus that the `@ModelAttribute` methods are invoked before the controller methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` are invoked.
The reason for that is the model object has to be created before any processing starts inside the
controller methods. If you annotate the respective class as `@ControllerAdvice`, then you can add values in Model which will be identified as global. This actually means that for every request a
default value exists, for every method in the response part.

**Additional facts!**

Below example, you can see a different way for annotating `@ModelAttribute`. It will add `Animal` object under "animal" attribute name.

```
/**
 * Populate model with attribute value for 'animal'.
 * This attribute will be added to the model by attribute name = 'animal'.
 * @return Taco
 */
@ModelAttribute(name="animal")
public Taco addAttributeAnimal() {
    return new Animal();
}
```

Below example you can see class level annotation for sessions.

```
/*Class level @SessionAttributes annotation specifies any model object like order attribute
  that should kept in session and available across multiple requests. Therefore the order
  object provided under @ModelAttribute(name="order") will be accessible across multiple sessions.*/
@SessionAttributes("order")

/**
 * Populate model with attribute value for 'order'.
 * This attribute will be added to the model by attribute name = 'order'.
 * *****Attention*****
 *      Class level @SessionAttributes("order") has declared and therefore the order attribute returns from
 *      this method will be accessible across multiple sessions.
 *      SPECIAL NOTE: Class level - @SessionAttributes("order")
 *                    Method level - @ModelAttribute("order")
 *                    This method will be only called once for a session and new order will be created since the "order"
 *                    will be there available across multiple sessions until SessionStatus set the session complete.
 * @return Order
 */
@ModelAttribute(name="order")
public Order order() {
    return new Order();
}
```

Just added something additional for your reference and hope this will help you. Happy coding!